# Would it be wrong to say that, since the gradient points toward the steepest ascent, it then also points toward the next greatest value?

Tags: vector-analysis, maxima-minima

The [gradient](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gradient) of a scalar field $f(\textbf{x})$ at a point $\bf{x}_{0}$, $\nabla f(\textbf{x}) |_{\textbf{x}_{0}}$, points toward the direction of steepest ascent. By a Taylor approximation, we have $$f(\textbf{x}_{0}+\Delta\textbf{x})\approx f(\textbf{x}_{0})+\bigg [\nabla f(\textbf{x}) |_{\textbf{x}_{0}}\cdot\frac{\Delta \textbf{x}}{||\Delta \textbf{x}||}\bigg ]||\Delta \textbf{x}||
$$
or, 
$$f(\textbf{x}_{0}+\Delta\textbf{x})\approx f(\textbf{x}_{0})+\nabla f(\textbf{x}) |_{\textbf{x}_{0}}\cdot \Delta \textbf{x}  ~.$$

But $\nabla f(\textbf{x}) |_{\textbf{x}_{0}}\cdot \Delta \textbf{x}$ ( and thus $f(\textbf{x}_{0}+\Delta\textbf{x})$ ) is maximum only when $\Delta \textbf{x}$ points in the same direction as $\nabla f(\textbf{x}) |_{\textbf{x}_{0}}$.

So would it be wrong to say that the gradient also points toward the next greatest value?

Comment: If the local maximum exists there, which requires the Hessian to be positive definite at that neighborhood or else one might ends up in a saddle point.

Comment: This is the basis for the idea of gradient descent. Which mind you, is fallible, but still a very common way to look for maxima (or really minima, conventionally) in complicated situations.

Comment: What do you mean by the "**next** maximum or minimum"?  If you are in 2 or more dimensions, the answer is "no". The gradient points in the direction of greatest increase  so if you go in that direction a short distance then recalculate the gradient, you will eventually get to a (local) maximum, but the path might curve.

Comment: I should've said next greatest value.

Comment: There is no such thing as "next greatest value".

Comment: @ChristianBlatter What I mean by next greatest value is, given a point $\textbf{x}_{0}$ and a change $||\delta \textbf{x}||$, there is a new point $\textbf{x}'$ given by $||\delta \textbf {x}||=||\textbf{x}'-\textbf{x}_{0}||$, and such that $f(\textbf{x}')=f(\textbf {x}_{0}+\delta \textbf {x}) \ge f(\textbf {x}_{0})$. And so the question is whether $\textbf{x}'-\textbf {x}_{0}=\delta \textbf x$ is parallel to $\nabla f (\textbf {x}) |_{\textbf{x}_{0}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x)+\nabla f(x)\cdot \Delta x+\frac{1}{2}\Delta x \cdot \nabla^2f(x)\cdot\Delta x + O(\Delta x^3)$

To get the maximum we go alongside $\Delta x$ until we reach a point where $\nabla f(x).\Delta x =0, \forall \Delta x$ which indicates that $\nabla f(x)=0$. Therefore the approximation becomes

$f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x)+\frac{1}{2}\Delta x \cdot \nabla^2f(x)\cdot\Delta x + O(\Delta x^3)$

But we must have $\forall \Delta x:f(x+\Delta x)\le f(x)$ at the point $x$ which indicates that $\forall \Delta x:\frac{1}{2}\Delta x \cdot \nabla^2f(x)\cdot\Delta x \ge0$ because we assume $\Vert \Delta x\Vert \rightarrow0$ or for very small changes, thus the dominant term becomes $\frac{1}{2}\Delta x \cdot \nabla^2f(x)\cdot\Delta x$ and $O(\Delta x^3) \rightarrow0$. Therefore the Hessian must be positive (semi) definite in order to have maximum at a region.

Equivalently to have a minimum, the Hessian must be negative (semi) definite which means $\forall \Delta x:\frac{1}{2}\Delta x \cdot \nabla^2f(x)\cdot\Delta x \le0$

$\nabla^2f(x)$ is the hessian matrix which have the information about the curvature of a scalar field contained in it and is defined $\left[\nabla^2f(x)\right]_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$ where $x_i$ is the $i$'th element of vector $x$.

If one knows $f(x)$ is bounded above and proves Hessian is positive (semi) definite and starts from an arbitrary initial guess $x_0$ and updates the initial guess in an iterative manner according to $x_{n+1}=x_{n}+G\nabla f(x), n=0,1,\cdot $, then in finite number of steps it can get arbitrarily close to maximum. $G$ is a matrix that varies from step to step (iteration $n$ to iteration $n+1$) at its most general form, but you can choose a constant scalar in its place like $\epsilon$. The difference will be at convergence speed. You do not need to exacly follow gradient, but every direction that makes an angle less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ with gradient is still a good direction (angle in the $n$-dimensional space). Such directions are called "Descent" directions.